# mv: cannot stat error

Tags: linux, bash, mv

mv: cannot stat error : No such file or directory error

this is my error

and this is my code

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "change word from read \n"
read a
read b
mv ${a} ${b}
printf "${b}\n"
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: The first input (`read a`) you enter should be the name of an existing file - and it seems it cannot be found.

Comment: Does the string you enter for `a` name an existing file?

Comment: Also, if `b` is a path and not just a simple name, all the directories must already exist; `mv` does not create directories.

Answer (score 2):

The file you are trying to mv does not exist.

You can check if it exists with:

```
if [ ! -f "$a" ]
then
  echo "File $a does not exist"
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your script a bit to check that the file exists and that the directory path will be created if need be. You are receiving your error because a file does not exist. "mv" will not create directories, so anything you enter in there has to be a directory path that exists.

---

So, instead of your original version:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "change word from read \n"
read a
read b
mv ${a} ${b}
printf "${b}\n"
```

I'd suggest the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "change word from read \n"
read -r a
read -r b

if [[ ! -f ${a} ]] ; then
  echo "Unable to locate ${a}...Exiting"
  exit 2
fi

### If you are renaming a file, remove "if" statement below ###
if [[ ! -d ${b} ]] ; then
  echo "Directory does not exist...Creating ${b}"
  mkdir -p "${b}" 
fi

mv "${a}" "${b}"
exit
```

Comment: What about the case where I want to rename my file with `mv`?

Comment: If he is trying to rename his file, then he could just remove the second "if" statement...although he would then only be able to rename the file and move it into already created directories.

I will update my answer to include a comment on removing the second if statement.

Comment: I suggest to add a check that a and b are not empty, and put quotes on variables always `if [[ ! -f "${a}" ]]`